# Apache Flink: Job recovery in IDE execution not working as expected

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpointing

I have a sample streaming `WordCount` example written in Flink (Scala). In it, I want to use externalized checkpointing to restore in case of failure. But it is not working as expected.

My code is as follows:

```
object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment
      .getExecutionEnvironment
      .setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("file:///path/to/checkpoint", true))

    // start a checkpoint every 1000 ms
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000)

    // set mode to exactly-once (this is the default)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)

    // make sure 500 ms of progress happen between checkpoints
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(500)

    // checkpoints have to complete within one minute, or are discarded
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointTimeout(60000)

    // prevent the tasks from failing if an error happens in their checkpointing, the checkpoint will just be declined.
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setFailOnCheckpointingErrors(false)

    // allow only one checkpoint to be in progress at the same time
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1)

    // prepare Kafka consumer properties
    val kafkaConsumerProperties = new Properties
    kafkaConsumerProperties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    kafkaConsumerProperties.setProperty("group.id", "flink")
    kafkaConsumerProperties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")

    // set up Kafka Consumer
    val kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("input", new SimpleStringSchema, kafkaConsumerProperties)

    println("Executing WordCount example.")

    // get text from Kafka
    val text = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer)

    val counts: DataStream[(String, Int)] = text
      // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
      .flatMap(_.toLowerCase.split("\\W+"))
      .filter(_.nonEmpty)
      .map((_, 1))
      // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
      .keyBy(0)
      .mapWithState((in: (String, Int), count: Option[Int]) =>
        count match {
          case Some(c) => ((in._1, c), Some(c + in._2))
          case None => ((in._1, 1), Some(in._2 + 1))
        })

    // emit result
    println("Printing result to stdout.")
    counts.print()

    // execute program
    env.execute("Streaming WordCount")
  }
}
```

The output I get after running program first time is:

```
(hi, 1)
(hi, 2)
```

The output I get after running program second time is:

```
(hi, 1)
```

My expectation is that running program second time should give me the following output:

```
(hi, 3)
```

Since I am a newbie to Apache Flink, I don't know how to achieve the expected result. Can anyone help me achieve the correct behavior?

Comment: And how do You stop the application?

Comment: @DominikWosiński - I am running the main class via IntelliJ Idea. Hence, the commands to run and stop the program are: Ctrl + Shift + F10 and Ctrl + F2, respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flink only restarts from the latest checkpoint if the application is restarted within the same execution (regular, automatic recovery).

If you cancel a job running in a local exeuction environment in the IDE, you kill the whole cluster and the job cannot be automatically recovered. Instead you need to start it again. In order to restart a new job from a savepoint (or externalized checkpoint), you need to provide a path to the persisted savepoint/checkpoint. Not sure if that is possible with a local execution environment.

IMO it is easier to play around with checkpointing and recovery on a local Flink instance and not within an IDE.

Comment: Thanks! It worked with a local instance of Flink cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue earlier, but I was able to make it work using MiniCluster. As mentioned here - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201702.mbox/%3CCAO_f5ND=0f+uBbReSfThMBi-bnY4BjGBozo3fzEsZujiovb_-g@mail.gmail.com%3E

I did not find lot of documentation about MiniCluster in the doc, so not sure it is recommended way or not.

On full restart of the job I had to write a small piece of code to identify latest checkpoint stored under checkpoint directory (/jobId/chk-*) which had _metadata directory. Then used `streamGraph.setSavepointRestoreSettings(SavepointRestoreSettings.forPath(s)` to restore the state from this checkpoint.